# Looking for SEGFAULT reason in really small snippet of code

Tags: c

Put simply, I'm writing really primitive implementation of single-linked list for basic database. I keep getting segfault when user requests to print the element listed under index higher than current amount of records in DB, but only when the difference is 1. For higher numbers it just triggers the error system that I wrote there.

The code is:

```
void print_spec(List* head)
{
int index, i, is_correct=1;
List * current=NULL; //List is typedef'ed structure consisting variables for data and pointer assumed to be bound to next element in list
printf("\nInput the element index: ");
scanf("%d", &index);
if(head!=NULL) 
{
    current=head;
    for (i=0; i<index; i++) 
    {
        if(current==NULL) 
        {
            printf("There is no such element");
            is_correct=0;
            break;
        }
        else current=current->next;
        }
    if(is_correct!=0) print(current); //this function simply prints out variables from element
}
else printf("List is empty, can't print");
}
```

I guess there's a little error, but as I mentioned in topic, I'm searching for it for like 4 hours now, having spent 2 hours on trial-and-error method considering possible range excession in loop counters, but recieved no proper results.

Comment: Has the list been constructed correctly?

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I suppose so, rest of features work well.
    typedef struct list{
    char imie[SIZE];
    char nazwisko[SIZE];
    int rok;
    struct list* next;
    } List;

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger? It should actually be your first reaction as a programmer when getting a crash. It will help you by telling you where the crash happened, show you the call stack so you know how you ended up there, and let you examine variables to help you understand why it crashed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg calling me a programmer is an insult to programmers community :P but thanks, i'll read into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATED

In the original code above, replace:

```
if(is_correct!=0) print(current);
```

with

```
if(is_correct!=0 && current != NULL)
    print(current);
else
    printf("Trying to print null List entry\n");
```

---

Suppose you have 10 entries in the list and the index happens to be 11.
Then here is what happens at i = 10:

```
for (i=0; i<index; i++) // i(10) < index(11)
{
    if(current==NULL) // not true as you have a 10th element
    {
        printf("There is no such element");
        is_correct=0;
        break;
    }
    else current=current->next; // current is now NULL as there is no 11th element
}
if(is_correct!=0) print(current); // crash, trying to print NULL
```

Comment: I see the problem now, I tried to workaround this by changing the loop's last line's if to 'else if', then adding  'else is_correct=0;', but, surprisingly, it didn't help... I'm worrying that I'm missing some logic here.

Comment: Works now, what's more I understand it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Its possible for your loop to exit because `i==index` while `current==NULL`.  `is_correct` is never set in this case and your program presumably fails when it tries to print a NULL list element.  You could avoid this and simplify the loop by changing your code to something like

```
for (i=0; i<index && current!=NULL; i++) 
{
    current=current->next;
}
if (current != NULL)
    print(current);
```

Comment: I've changed my code to such version but it only resulted in printing "not found" whatever the inputted index was. Again I'm astonished.

Comment: @Szarlej There was a daft error in my suggested code.  Its now corrected in case you're interested in understanding an alternative solution